# How to divide array into array of subarray of particular size in mongodb aggreagtion

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want to divide the customer array into subarray if the array length exceeds 40, for example,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6pgl.jpg) if the customer array has 80 objects in it, it should divide into two sub-array of size 40

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do following:

1. find starting indexes for each subarray in the raw array by using `$range`; you get an array that stored the starting indices
2. use `$slice` to get each slice of subarray
3. use `$map` to group the slices back into a single array

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bm6D3LG_nb2) for your reference. The array size is parameterized so you may easily replace it with your array size of 40.